# Airflow upstart script enters stop/waiting state immediately after start/running state

Tags: ubuntu, service, upstart, airflow

I'm trying to run this upstart script from the official repo for airflow: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/scripts/upstart/airflow-webserver.conf

```
start on started networking
stop on (deconfiguring-networking or runlevel [016])

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid airflow
setgid airflow

exec usr/local/bin/airflow webserver
```

When I run it this is the output:

```
$ sudo service airflow-webserver start
airflow-webserver start/running, process 7612

$ sudo service airflow-webserver status
airflow-webserver stop/waiting
```

But just doing `exec /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver` will run it perfectly without any hiccups, which is puzzling. Does anyone know why this is happening?

---

* You can get airflow with `pip install airflow` to test in case you need to see for yourselves.

Comment: Does airflow still work as intended despite the message? <I have a home server that says that when php5-fpm is started. However, it still works as intended...>

Comment: @JefréN. unfortunately not.

Comment: In that top 'codeblock', does it really say `exec usr/local/bin/airflow webserver` instead of `exec /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver`?

Comment: @JefréN. yes, but it actually doesn't matter for the upstart script. I've figured out the problem, which is that I neglected that upstart does not get environment variables from `/etc/profile`, and I needed to set them in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstart runs in a clean environment, meaning that it won't use the variables in `/etc/environment`. This means you have to set `AIRFLOW_HOME` and `AIRFLOW_CONFIG` again.

```
description "Airflow webserver daemon"

start on started networking
stop on (deconfiguring-networking or runlevel [016])

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid airflow
setgid airflow

# I omitted all of the below because I assumed 
# it would pick it up from the already defined env
env AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/path/to/airflow/airflow.cfg
env AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/airflow
export AIRFLOW_CONFIG
export AIRFLOW_HOME

exec usr/local/bin/airflow webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in Ubuntu 16:
(The init scripts are taken from the incubator-airflow git repo)

```
$ sudo cp incubator-airflow/scripts/systemd/*.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

In each service file, change user and group lines to the owner of 
 directory, in my case - ubuntu and modify ExecStart:

```
User=ubuntu

Group=ubuntu

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow  webserver --pid $AIRFLOW_HOME/webserver.pid
```

keep in mind that ExecStart line is different in every service line.

Then:

```
$ sudo cp incubator-airflow/scripts/systemd/*.conf /etc/tmpfiles.d/
$ sudo mkdir /etc/sysconfig
$ sudo cp incubator-airflow/scripts/systemd/airflow /etc/sysconfig/airflow
```

Add the following lines to /etc/sysconfig/airflow:

```
AIRFLOW_CONFIG=YOUR_airflow_home/airflow.cfg

AIRFLOW_HOME=YOUR_airflow_home
```

Finally:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver
```

(Or any other airflow service)

Good Luck!